# AWS - Copying snapshot to another region automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS to launch a EC2 instance. Fortunately I did it without problem.

What I need now is to make a backup of the data. 
I think snapshot is a good way to do it. I have been doing some research and I found a good tool to do it automatically (https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup).
The problem is that I think it is not enough to make snapshots. In my opinion a copy of the last snapshot needs to be in another region, but I don't know how to do it automatically. I have been searching on internet and only found this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-snapshot.html. The problem is that I don't know the snapshot id (considering it is generated automatically by the first tool I mentioned).

The question is: Do you know any tool that can help me with this problem? If don't, do you know another approach to get a solution.

It is important to know that the service which is given doesn't need to be up 24 hs. 
It is my first time using servers so I don't know how long a region in amazon can be down.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to know a volume ID to use `copy-snapshot` in the AWS CLI. When executing the command you provide a value to the  `--source-snapshot-id` option. This specifies the ID of the snapshot you want to copy. A snapshot can be copied in the same region or to another region via the `--destination-region` option.

You can simply call [create-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html) and then [copy-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-snapshot.html) giving it the generated snapshot ID to copy the snapshot to another region. This could be automated via a cron job if necessary.

Comment: Hi!! thank you for your answer. I edited my post. I didn't mean "volume id" but "snaphot id". The tool I mentioned can be executed by chron and it generates a random "snapshot id" so these is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cron job to invoke aws cli which can copy the snapshots to an S3 bucket 'A'. And, cross region bucket replication can be enabled from the source bucket 'A' in region 1 to destination bucket 'B' in region 2. Whenever a snapshot is uploaded to 'A', it'll get replicated to 'B' as well. So, in case first region becomes offline, you can restore volumes from the snapshots in 'B' bucket in region 2.

Comment: You cannot specify a bucket when using copy-snapshot from the CLI. The snapshots are stored in S3 but you do not have control over their bucket. copy-snapshot makes a copy of an existing snapshot in the same region or in another region.